# Filter list using Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, .net

```
// i have a class named "person" and have two member Name i.e string variable and age i.e int

//created list to store the object of class person
List<person> list = new List<person>();

// added some object in list 

//using lambda exp[ression to filter the object
var newlist = list.Where(x => x.Age>60);


            //printing 
            foreach ( var li in newlist)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(li.Name);
            }

//
```

i'm new to Lambda expression and trying to find out a way to return just property Name in newlist instead of the whole object.
for example::

var newlist = list.Where(//lambda expression); this should return string,let say if we use object x then x.name if x.age>60.

i tried some hit and trial but didn't work.

Comment: Have you looked a [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use Linq's `Select` after the `Where` clause:

```
var namesList = list.Where(x => x.Age > 60)
                    .Select(x => x.Name)
                    .ToList();
```

Note that Linq methods will return an `IEnumerable<T>`, if you want a `List<T>` back, you need to call `ToList()` after the query.